# How to backup mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I have a mongodb(replica set) and I want to dump this database, I know I can dump a mongodb with a simple cli command and It's working here. But I'm trying to use the same command to dump a replica set, Am I supposed to use the same command?

```
mongodump -h "example-shard01:27017,example-shard02:27017,example-shard03:27017" --username=myusername --password=mypass --out=/destination
```

Comment: `mongodump` can be used for a backup of data from a replica set (take a look at the various options specific to replica-set data backup for this command) There are other ways to backup/restore as described at: [MongoDB Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the replica set in connection string URI. Similar to this:

```
"example-shard01:27017,example-shard02:27017,example-shard03:27017/?replicaSet=myRepl"
```

Your hostnames are bit strange, they look more like a shards in a sharded cluster. Don't mix them.

Comment: I had to change -h to --uri "mongodb://..." too, then it worked!